# Issue with FieldNorm in Solr

Tags: search, solr, lucene, similarity

I am working on movie name search using Apache Solr.

I have nullified tf & idf by inherting the DefaultSimilarity Lucene Class and  overriding both tf and idf functions.

I will elaborate my problem with an example.
Search on "Shades of Blue" yields the following results.

1. Forty Shades of Blue
2. Shades of blue

Both the above documents have received same scores.

A little investigation pointed me to FieldNorm used by lucene while computing scores. For both the above documents, the FieldNorm is same. But, it should be different.

Moreover, I observed the following,

1. when document_length is 1, fieldNorm is 1
2. when document_length is 2, fieldNorm is 0.625
3. when document_length is 3, fieldNorm is 0.5
4. when document_length is 4, fieldNorm is 0.5
5. when document_length is 5, fieldNorm is 0.4325

   - How is FieldNorm calculated?
   - In above case, why for documents with length 3 & 4 have same fieldNorms.
   - Is there anything i missed out? Essentially I want the documents with lesser number of tokens be matched higher when same phrases are matched.

Comment: @femtoRgon: Yes. This seems to be the same issue... My max numTerms for the field is 20.. I will override the encodeNormValue & decodeNormValue  to accomodate only these 20 categories according to the LengthNorm value.. will keep you posted.. Thank you very much..

Comment: @femtoRgon: over-riding these two methods with custom one helped for my use case.